# "There was an error connecting to https://localhost:3443/users/login."

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I'm attempting the final assignment for my course but not getting anywhere due to Oauth2 authentication difficulties. I'm having a great deal of difficulty resolving this! I think it may be due to the fact I'm using a work laptop which is SOE'd and pretty locked down.

I just don't know where to look to resolve this. Any suggestions?

**Steps to replicate**
1. I've set my Oauth2 application up in Facebook and with Site URL setting as https://localhost:3443/users/facebook/callback
2. When I attempt ANY method (get, post, put etc) on this url, I get the below.

**I've tried:**
**1.** bypassing my company's firewall and hotspotting my phone; note that this a workaround I use to install NPM packages as my company seems to block NPM
**2.** my course's forum\Stack exchange. It seems that I'm the only person in the galaxy that this has affected.
**3.** F12 in CHrome - there are no messages in the console
**4.** inserting debug clues in the `user` route, viz;

```
router.get('/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook'),
    function(req, res){
        console.log('routergetfacebook');//------------------------debug
    });

router.get('/facebook/callback', function(req,res,next){
  console.log('router.get-facebook-callback');//------------------------debug
```

In Chrome

> This site can’t be reached

In Postman:

> **Could not get any response**
>
> There was an error connecting to https://localhost:3443/users/login.
>   Why this might have happened:
>
> **The server couldn't send a response:** Ensure that the backend is working properly
>
> **Self-signed SSL certificates are being blocked:** Fix this by turning off 'SSL certificate verification' in Settings > General
>
> **Client certificates are required for this server:** Fix this by adding client certificates in Settings > Certificates
>
> **Proxy configured incorrectly** Ensure that proxy is configured correctly in Settings > Proxy
>
> **Request timeout**: Change request timeout in Settings > General

Comment: Does the application is running on the port 3443 localhost? can you go over once https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-facebook and check

Comment: Yes it works perfectly. I still don't now why mine doesn't work...